# Have DIV Automatically Resize With Content - CSS

Tags: html, css

Direct Link to Issue: http://s18.postimg.org/f55rkfl1l/issue.png

```
<div class="overall_content">
        <div class="content">
            <p>jessicaPhotography<br><img src="images/heart.png"></p>
            <div class="content_picture">   
                    <p class="main">
                    This is where the revolving images will appea
                    This is where the revolving images will appea
                    This is where the revolving images will appea
                    This is where the revolving images will appea
                    This is where the revolving images will appea
                    </p> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Can someone help me understand why I cannot get my content div to expand with the text within the paragraph tag.  Here is my css:

```
html, body, header, p, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, img, .content {
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
}

html {
background: url('images/background_gradient.png') repeat;
}

header {
width: 100%;
height: 30px;
background: rgb(0,0,0);
}

.overall_content {
width: 84%;
height: 100%;
background: rgb(255,255,255);
margin: 0px auto;
margin-top: .5%;
position: relative;
}

.content {
width: 98%;
height: 98%;
background: rgb(0,0,0);
position: absolute;
top: 1%;
left: 1%;
}
```

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION**

```
.content_picture {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

/********************************/
/* Intrinsic Content Properties */
/********************************/

.content p.main {
color: rgb(255,255,255);
font-family: Verdana, Arial;
font-size: 18px;
padding: 25px;

}
```

Comment: Please show css for: `content_picture` and `main`

Comment: adding now thanks.. one sec

Comment: .content will always be 98% height of .overall_content.  @Sven provides a solution for you below.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have set a fixed width and height. `.content` will have at every time 98% of the size of `.overall-content`, independent from its content.
when you set the height to auto that should solve your problem.

Comment: fixed this issue.. that was quick.. again, appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `height` limit, then if you add some text, the div will be less or more tall (adapted to your content... ;)